# Automatic merging of duplicate cells under common ID

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I have data in column A with IDs and a column B with data for those IDs.
Right now I have multiple (usually 2-3) rows with the same ID but different data. What formula to use to merge those into one row per ID?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: Here is what I have put together [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-ZEEHZmNxDuajK08HM6wwNICtf5IG_jo_cIygttGMLY) but I don't think I have gone the right direction. I have found this piece of code `=if(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)=1,A1,"")` but I wasn't able to rebuild it for my use because that basically just hides the ID whenever that would be a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)))\ 
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY(A2:B; 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B"; 0); "offset 1"; 0)<>""; 
 QUERY(A2:B; 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B limit 0"); )); ; 999^99)))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: In my spreadsheet your formula stacks the output columns below each other AND it seems like it is also assorted. But I cannot find out why. I have watched some videos and I understand how Query works but it is still above my skills to solve it myself for now. Link to my test spreadsheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-ZEEHZmNxDuajK08HM6wwNICtf5IG_jo_cIygttGMLY/edit#gid=2034714408&range=F2)

Comment: @MarekMarhoul fixed. answer and your sheet updated

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much

Comment: Quick question about this formula - is it possible to merge exactly like this but with a comma and space instead of just space?

Comment: @MarekMarhoul sure: `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT({UNIQUE(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)))\ 
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY(A2:B; 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B"; 0); "offset 1"; 0)<>""; 
 QUERY(A2:B; 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B limit 0")&","; )); ; 999^99)))});
 ",$"; ))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahlip.png

Comment: Perfect, thank you again!