# Merging cells based on same ID but divided into categories (columns)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I receive a pretty extent list of material that has been delivered and every single product is in a separate row. That means for one order I have easily a lot over 15 rows and I need to merge the products for further data processing.

Following image depicts the final output I am looking for.
[image]

I am using various formulas and steps to achieve this, one of them being a formula I got as an answer to my very similar step from a previous [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130963/automatic-merging-of-duplicate-cells-under-common-id):

`=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(INDIRECT("Delivered!A2:A"&COUNTA(Delivered!A1:A)))\ TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY(Delivered!A2:B; "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B"; 0); "offset 1"; 0)<>""; QUERY(Delivered!A2:B; "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B limit 0"); )); ; 999^99)))})`

This seems to be the part that isn't working properly but I cannot find out why.
Also, my solution is unnecessarily complicated (too many steps that could be solved in fewer formulas I bet)

[My spreadsheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h9F2UZ9S9EW1m_BoZsB7UNd9JoP-GxEbZ6rrMBbySQA) with some explanation on every sheet. Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE({UNIQUE(INDIRECT("Delivered!A2:A"&COUNTA(Delivered!A1:A)))\ 
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY(Delivered!A2:B; 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B"; 0); 
 "offset 1"; 0)<>""; QUERY(Delivered!A2:B; 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B limit 0"); )); ; 999^99)))\ 
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY(Delivered!A2:C; 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot C"; 0); 
 "offset 1"; 0)<>""; QUERY(Delivered!A2:C;
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot C limit 0"); )); ; 999^99)))\
 REGEXREPLACE(UNIQUE(INDIRECT("Delivered!A2:A"&COUNTA(Delivered!A1:A))); ".*"; )\
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY(Delivered!A2:E; 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot E"; 0); 
 "offset 1"; 0)<>""; QUERY(Delivered!A2:E; 
 "select count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot E limit 0"); )); ; 999^99)))}; 
 ",$"; ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind when saying it could be a lot simpler and it is working perfectly. If I am correct, it outputs codes in column B into B because they are in B, right? Not because the column F ("Destination column") contains that information it should be in B. Is that function reasonably simple to accomplish or would that mean a complete rework of the formula you posted?

Comment: not sure I follow but try: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h9F2UZ9S9EW1m_BoZsB7UNd9JoP-GxEbZ6rrMBbySQA/edit#gid=1489453324